# Synology NAS network drive slows down Windows 8 computer

Tags: windows, synology, network-drive

I have mapped multiple shared folders from my Synology NAS as network drives to my pc, so they look like real drives (D:, E:, F: etc.).

Unfortunately, even with a very stable LAN collection, it does not work as expected. Sometimes, Windows fails to list the files/folders. Or when I open any program and want to save a file ("Save As"), it takes over a minute until it can display my hard drives ("This PC")!

I cannot work like that, so what is the solution? Are there programs which do similar things and are more stable?

Comment: What kind of LAN connection are you using? Wired or WiFi? What kind of adaptor? How is everything connected together? Also, which Synology model do you have (they vary greatly) and what kind of disks have you put in it? How are they configured? All can have an impact.

Comment: Wired of course, Synology 415+ with 4 identical 4 TB WD Red disks.